# Implementation of hash map

Tags: c++, interview-questions, hash-map

I was asked to implement a hash map in this phone interview (screen-share), so time was limited and this is what I came up with. I'd appreciate if someone can take a minute to critique/review it and help me improve.

[Here](http://rextester.com/YJX95968) is an online version of the code.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

class Node{
public:
    Node(){}
    Node(int k, int v):key(k), value(v){}
    int key, value;
};

class HashMap {
private:
    list<Node*> data[SIZE];

public:
    ~HashMap();
    Node* get(int key);
    void put(int key, int value);

    int hashFn(int val){ return val % 13; }
};

Node* HashMap::get(int key){
    int hashValue = hashFn(key);
    int bucket = hashValue % SIZE;
    list<Node*>::iterator it = data[bucket].begin();

    while(it != data[bucket].end()){

        Node ** d = &(*it); 
        if((*d)->key == key){
            return *d;
        }

        it++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void HashMap::put(int key, int value){
    int hashValue = hashFn(key);
    int bucket = hashValue % SIZE;
    Node* node = this->get(key);
    if(node == NULL){
        data[bucket].push_front(new Node(key, value));
    }
    else{
        node->value = value;
    }
}

HashMap::~HashMap(){
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        list<Node*>& val = data[i];
        for(list<Node*>::iterator it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); it++){
            Node* n = *it;
            delete n;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    HashMap map;
    cout << "Finding 5: " << map.get(5) << endl;  // -1
    map.put(5, 10);
    map.put(5, 11);
    cout << "Finding 5: " << map.get(5)->value;  // 11
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: A destructor is not enough. You have forgotten the rule of three.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned this was a part of telephonic interview and the focus here was on implementing get() and put(). However, I do agree with you and this definitely lacks the rule of three!

Comment: You have not declared the destructor in the class body.

Comment: Yea, I posted the code on Mat's request. Forgot to update both the places.

Comment: Probably I should have also implemented the rules of three for the interviewer.

Answer (score 4):

**Some obvious problems**

1. It leaks memory (every `new`ly allocated `Node`) when the Hashmap leaves the scope.
2. A delete/remove function is missing.
3. <strike>It doesn't replace the value within the existing `Node` on repeated `put`s with the same key but instead adds an additional `Node` every time.</strike>
4. The size is fixed and therefore the hashmap `get` quickly degenerates into linked list search.
5. Key and value types aren't generic.

**Some positive things**

- It implements a hashmap
- uses hash-lookup for search
- returns correct results

Comment: 1. when hashmap leaves the scope, destructor would be called upon its members, aka list and when it gets destroyed, it would call the destructor on its members and hence it won't be a memory leak ?

Comment: 3. In fact it does replace the value. I see if a node exists in the map, I return that instead and modify the value of that node.

Comment: 4. Yes, size is fixed, but a lot depends on the hashFunction to distribute the elements properly. What I wrote was a dummy function.

Comment: @brainydexter: For 1., no. The destructor for a `List<T*>` (or any other standard container) doesn't call delete on the pointers it contains.

Comment: @Mat Added destructor code also.

Comment: @brainydexter: Yes, I was wrong about 3., too late yesterday evening...

Comment: @brainydexter: You'd have to enlargen the HashMap and rehash all entries at a certain filling-factor to prevent degeneration to linked list search with lots of entries. With the given hash it's pointless though, you'd use at most 13 buckets even if you allocate more than that.

Comment: @Patrick : agreed.

Answer (score 3):

The first two things I noticed:

1. Drop the pointers. They give you no advantage. Use value objects.
2. Drop the linked list. It’s *sluggishly* slow. I have no idea why hash maps collision resolution, when taught in class, always mentions lists – probably because it makes the asymptotic runtime analysis easier. They are almost *always* slower.

Dropping pointers has the nice effect of plugging the leaks and making the code easier – in particular, the rule of three is then trivially satisfied – and more efficient.

Then, since `Node` is just an aggregate, I’d use `std::pair`.

For a real implementation, `hashFn` shouldn’t be a function inside the hash map, it should be a user-supplied function, depending on the type of data (potentially even if the type is not generic, since different data has different characteristics). But a real implementation also would need to be resizable and configurable by load factor.

Answer (score 2):

```
int hashValue = hashFn(key);
int bucket = hashValue % SIZE;
```

I'd suggest having a `bucket(key)` function that returns the bucket rather then repeating this piece of code. I'd also create a Bucket class to handle the per-bucket logic. Then your get function would look like:

```
Node * HashMap::get(int key)
{
    return bucket(key).get(key);
}
```

Of course, Bucket::get would have more complicated logic than here, but I think it would simplify your code overall.

```
    Node ** d = &(*it);
```

Its not clear this helps over using the iterator directly in the following lines.

```
list<Node*>::iterator it = data[bucket].begin();

while(it != data[bucket].end()){
```

Why not use a standard for loop here?

```
list<Node*> data[SIZE];
```

Linked lists are almost always the wrong choice. There are slower for every case except inserting/deleting in the middle. You don't use that here, so you should probably use a `vector` not a `list`.

Comment: I agree with creating a bucket function but not quite sure if I understood making a Bucket class ? As for using a while loop over for loop, there was no particular reason, just a style of accessing iterators I prefer. And, though I agree with your suggestion of `vector<Node*> data`, but I also think, whenever we do a lookup based on a key, we have to loop through each element to find it and hence O(n) time. Similarly for insert, I am just inserting this at the beginning which is O(1), so I am not sure how would a vector be better in this case ?

Comment: If I were to store elements in a sorted manner, I could use binary search on the vector to reduce lookup time to O(lg n) from O(n) where n is the size of vector. This would increase the insertion time though. Inserting element in a sorted array would take O(n) time. So am not sure if we are actually gaining that much

Comment: @brainydexter, A Bucket Class would hold your list<> of  Nodes and provide `get` and `set` methods just for items which fit into that list.

Comment: @brainydexter, lookup on a vector and list will both be O(n), but vector has a smaller O(n). A vector just to move forward in memory to iterate, but a list has to read a pointer and jump to a completely different memory location.

Comment: @brainydexter, both list and vectors keep track of the location of the last element, so both have O(1) insert at the end. You aren't gaining anything by inserting at the beginning. I'm not exactly sure how the insertion time itself compares between the two methods. Inserting a vector is usually faster, because there is less to do, but if it runs out of capacity it can be more expensive.

Comment: @brainydexter, yes you could do a sorted vector. But then the idea in a hash is that you could get speed by not putting things into the same bucket, so I wouldn't focus on optimizing hash collisions.

Comment: About sorted vector, here is what I meant: `vector<Node*> data[SIZE]`. Now, after finding the right bucket, one can search on the vector at this bucket `data[bucket]` (which is a type of vector<Node*>). This lookup can be brought down to O(lg N). I'm not sure what you meant there by putting things into the same bucket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4454/discussion-between-brainydexter-and-winston-ewert)